# I installed Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 to be dual-booted with windows 8.1, but after the restart, it only boots to windows.

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, ubuntu-gnome

Thank you for your support and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have somehow lost your grub boot manager and is using Windows boot manager.  You can get the grub boot manager by reinstalling grub.

Perform the following:

Reinstall grub:

```
1  boot to the Ubuntu installation disk
2  Run the "Try Ubuntu" option
3) Bring up a terminal (Search for "terminal" Ubuntu launch/search button)
```

Run these commands (exactly):

```
 a) sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt  # Make "X" the partition that has Ubuntu installed (i.e. /dev/sda2).
 b) for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
 c) sudo chroot /mnt
 d) update-grub
 e) if no errors skip this "e" section
     grub-install /dev/sdX (x is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda)
     update-grub 5) Reboot the system
```